# 'main()' is only available in application extensions for iOS 14.0 or newer

Tags: swift, widgetkit

I added widget target in my app, and I tried to the iOS 14 and newer condition for that, but I still got this error:

> 'main()' is only available in application extensions for iOS 14.0 or
> newer

```
@available(iOSApplicationExtension 14.0, *)
@main
struct Widget: SwiftUI.Widget {
    let kind: String = "Widget"

   var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            WidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
}
```

That @available is the one that Xcode suggested me

[image: screenshot]

Could anyone help me on that?

Comment: You used the wrong "available". https://nshipster.com/available/

Comment: @Jessy it's the one that xcode suggest me to add

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9):

In the file where your put '@main', look at the target membership on the right sidebar, remove your main app as a target and leave your widget extension.

Answer (score 5):

If you added or already had an extension you should check that the deployment info for you extension is 14.0.

See screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hDVH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

does your project use xcodegen ?
if no, just change target version.
if yes, config your project.yml, and remember configure your target iOS version 14.1 but not 14.0.
you can also see this [Add deploymentTarget to widget in XcodeGen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64199060/add-deploymenttarget-to-widget-in-xcodegen/67238462#67238462)