# Add deploymentTarget to widget in XcodeGen

Tags: swift, xcodegen

I'm beginner at XcodeGen and tried to add the iOS 14's widget target to my app

```
Widget:
type: app-extension
platform: iOS
settings:
  INFOPLIST_FILE: PIAWidget/Info.plist
  PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER_Release: Development - Widget Extension
  OTHER_LDFLAGS: $(inherited) -framework WidgetKit
configFiles:
  Debug: Configuration/AppExtension-iOS.xcconfig
  Release: Configuration/AppExtension-iOS.xcconfig
sources:
  - path: Widget
    name: "Extension: Widget"
```

In the option of the project.yml, the deployment target is iOS 13.0

```
 options:
  deploymentTarget:
    macOS: "10.14"
    iOS: "13.0"
    tvOS: "13.0"
  settingPresets: none
  createIntermediateGroups: true
  carthageExecutablePath: Vendor/carthage.command
  carthageBuildPath: ${APP_CARTHAGE_BUILD_PATH}
  usesTabs: false
  indentWidth: 3
  tabWidth: 3
```

In the widget swift class, there is `@main` that asked me to add: `@available`

```
@available(iOSApplicationExtension 14.0, *)
@main
```

But after adding it, it still show me that error:

```
'main()' is only available in application extensions for iOS 14.0 or newer
```

That is why, I thought maybe I have to add a `deploymentTarget` in the widget section. And as I searched it should be like that:

```
  Widget:
    type: app-extension
    platform: iOS
    deploymentTarget:
      iOS: "14.0"
    settings:
      INFOPLIST_FILE: PIAWidget/Info.plist
      PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER_Release: Piavet Development - Widget Extension
      OTHER_LDFLAGS: $(inherited) -framework WidgetKit
    configFiles:
      Debug: Configuration/AppExtension-iOS.xcconfig
      Release: Configuration/AppExtension-iOS.xcconfig
    sources:
      - path: Widget
        name: "Extension: Widget"
```

But I still got the error. Could anyone help me on that?

Answer (score 1):

change deploymentTarget from 14.0 to 14.1
like this

```
    deploymentTarget:
      iOS: "14.1"
```